# Trying to create my first node.js application: /bin/sh: 1: fpm: not found

Tags: node.js, nw.js

I have follow this steps to creae my first node.js application:

https://www.codementor.io/javascript/tutorial/how-to-create-cross-platform-desktop-apps-with-nwjs

The problem: I can not find anything at `klout/dist` directory after running `gulp pack:linux64:deb`, any help?

This is the output after `gulp pack:linux64:deb`:

https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/ac0708acf689b7d6491d

and this is the output after `gulp build:linux64`

https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/65104ee6f7f109f3a41e

Comment: It seems that `fpm` is missing

Comment: @kaytrance I have run `sudo npm install fpm` and `sudo npm install --save fpm` but I still get that `/bin/sh: 1: fpm: not found`.. And, of course, `/dist` is still empty, any idea?

Comment: You most probably have to install it globally with `npm install -g fpm`

Comment: @kaytrance thanks! it works

Comment: then, if don't mind I will repost it as an answer so you could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to logs you provided the `fpm` is missing. You have to install it globally for build to work by

```
npm install -g fpm
```

Comment: Pretty sure this answer is outdated. I tried this myself recently and it installed completely the wrong thing. Following the instructions here gave me the correct fpm: https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html